# SVG 3D rotation: rotating an SVG around the X axis to create the illusion of a floor

Tags: svg

I am trying to 3D rotate this SVG (around the X axis) to create the illusion of a floor.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/procrastinator.mx/floor.svg

Any ideas how I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean so it faces like this?

./-----------\     if yes then in inkscape use the node editor to relocate the edges to the
/-------------\    appropriate place..

```
if it's an animation then, rotate the edges (as in from (0,0) to (-1,1)) step by step (depending on the size of the step) and save each layer (or rotation)
```